# Solidity Infinite Gas Requiriment issue

Tags: solidity

The Solidity Static Analysis warns that this code has infinite Gas requirement, probably due to a infinite loop, but I'm a beginner, and a really don't know how to fix it.
This contract was made for check the distribution and transaction of a product, how can I improve it?

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.6.2;

contract casoDosTomates{

    address payable CICA = 0x14723A09ACff6D2A60DcdF7aA4AFf308FDDC160C;
    address payable produtores = 0x4B0897b0513fdC7C541B6d9D7E929C4e5364D2dB;
    uint8 anos = 0;
    uint8 jurisprudencia = 5;
    uint valorDoTomateKG = 200 wei ;
    uint8 quantidadeDeProdutores = 5 ;

    function setExpectativa (bool trueOrFalse) payable public{
        bool sementesDistribuidas = trueOrFalse;
        if (sementesDistribuidas == true){  
            anos++;
        }

            else {

                if (anos >= jurisprudencia){

                    uint multa = (valorDoTomateKG * quantidadeDeProdutores);
                    produtores.transfer(multa);
            }

                    else{

                        uint multa = 500 wei;
                        produtores.transfer(multa);
        }      

    }
}

    function getAnos() view public returns (uint){
        return anos;
    }

    function getBalance() view public returns (uint){
        return produtores.balance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue here is that smart contracts can not just create ether ex machina, they must accept ether from a msg.sender address that is interacting with your contract and store it within the contract for future use, if the sender has the required ether (and the gas to pay for transaction).

The value

```
uint valorDoTomateKG = 200 wei ;
```

Is **not** intended to be transferred and does **not** create ether/wei.

Ether can **only** be mined or transferred from another address that already own some, it can not be created programmatically.

Instead, **valorDoTomateKG** (or any other value with a denomination, such a wei, finney or ether) is intended to be used in conditionals to ensure the value of the ether being passed to a contract meets some requirement for sanity checks/state validation using the **require** function, which will revert the contract's internal state when the conditional evaluates to false. Like this

```
modifier insufficientBalance(){
    require(address(this).balance > valorDoTomateKG * quantidadeDeProdutores, "insufficient balance");
    _;
}
```

With the result contract looking something like this

```
//@todo make a Produtores a contract in this project and import into this file

contract casoDosTomates{
    address payable CICA = 0x14723A09ACff6D2A60DcdF7aA4AFf308FDDC160C;
    address payable proxy= 0x4B0897b0513fdC7C541B6d9D7E929C4e5364D2dB;
    address owner; //the address which created this contract
    uint8 anos = 0;
    uint8 jurisprudencia = 5;
    uint valorDoTomateKG = 200 wei ;
    bool internal sementesDistribuidas;
    //dynamic array of productores contracts
    address[] productores;

    modifier insufficientBalance(){
        require(address(this).balance > valorDoTomateKG * quantidadeDeProdutores(), "insufficient balance");
        _;
    }
    modifier onlyOwner(){
        require(msg.sender == owner, "address is not this contract's owner");
        _;
    }
    modifier producersNotMax(){
        require(productores.length < quantidadeDeProdutores(), "productores size can not exceed 5");
        _;
    }
    modifier productoresNotZero(){
        require(productores.length > 0, "no productores registered");
        _;
    }
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        sementesDistribuidas = true;
        //initialize empty dynamic array
        produtores = address[]();
    }
    function quantidadeDeProdutores() internal {
        return Produtores.length;
    }
    //Producer contracts can call this method to add themselves as a Produtor
    function addProdutor() public produtoresNotMax {
        //@todo use reflection to ensure msg.sender is a producer contract using require
        produtores.push(msg.sender);
    }
    //this should only be callable by the contract's owner, otherwise any address may execute it
    function accumulate() public onlyOwner produtoresNotZero {
        if (sementesDistribuidas == true){
            //calls 0-5 accumulate ether in this contract's balance
            address(produtores[anos]).balance = msg.sender.value;
            anos++;
            if(anos >= jurisprudencia){
                sementesDistribuidas = false;
            }
        }
        else {
            //on 6th call, perform transfer
            setExpectativa();
        }
    }

    function setExpectativa () internal payable onlyOwner produtoresNotZero {
        require(anos >= jurisprudencia);

        if(sementesDistribuidas == false){
            //emulate intent of the line uint multa = (valorDoTomateKG * quantidadeDeProdutores);, by getting the balance of each produtores
            uint256 sum = 0;
            //
            //iterate over each produtores
            //grabbing their current balance if greater than valorDoTomateKG 
            for(uint i = 0; i < produtores.length; i++){
                address p = address(produtores[i]);
                require(p.balance >= valorDoTomateKG, "insufficient Productores balance");

                sum += p.balance;
                p.balance = 0;
            }
            // transfer fund from produtores sum to this contract
            address(this).transfer(sum);
        }
        else {
            //transfer this contract's balance to the proxy's address
            require(address(this).balance > 0 wei, "no balance in contract");

            proxy.transfer(address(this).balance);
            address(this).balance = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The spirit of your original contract has been preserved as best as possible without access to the technical specifications of the project.

Please be aware that I have not compiled this code and you may have to modify this as needs be, since this code has not been tested, is not safe and does not address logic or security issues such as reentrancey (since external contracts are being used) or overflow/underflow of variables, among other concerns, like whether or not the external addresses **0x14723A09ACff6D2A60DcdF7aA4AFf308FDDC160C** and **0x4B0897b0513fdC7C541B6d9D7E929C4e5364D2dB** can be trusted.